# sort magento list page by price descending order

Tags: sorting, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am using magento ver. 1.9.2.3 .I am trying to add price descend sort in list page.How can i do that?.I tried to add through local.xml by adding below code, but not working.Any help is appreciable....

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- Change default direction for simple searches -->
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <!-- Change default direction for advanced searches -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>

    <!-- Change default direction for a category without layered navigation -->
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <!-- Change default direction for a category with layered navigation -->
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <!-- Change default direction for category with ID 3 -->
    <CATEGORY_3>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>                                   
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_3>
</layout>
```

Comment: do you want to auto sort by price descend order in list.phtml?

Comment: you checked this? http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/                         or you want only price descend what about all filters, you want to remove them all?

Comment: i think default behaviour is price ascending order i need to change to  descending  order

Comment: then try this tutorial i think your problem solved by this and disble local.xml to see changes http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-sort-products-in-the-category-products-listing.html#gref

Answer (score 0):

Go to /app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml
and find

```
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
</option>
```

Replace

```
<?php if ($_order != 'Price'): ?>
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
</option>
<?php else: ?>
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'asc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ': Low to High' ?>
</option> 
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key) && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->__($_order) . ': High to Low' ?>
</option> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Don't forget clear your cache